# Dreamweaver CS6 Fluid Grid: width fixed with padding

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I am new to Dreamweaver Fluid Grid. I set the width to 100% and change the margins to 0. When I add padding, it begins to scroll to the right. I want to use padding because I want to have a border of space around the text/image.I want the width to stay fixed.

Please give me some solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is getting added to the width. To fix this add to your .css file

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

This will make the padding occur within the width rather than adding to it

https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

Comment: I know, I want to add padding.

Comment: I know. The original link may have been better because it talks about browser support (http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) - you may be using an older browser which is fine. Instead of making the width 100% will it work to make it display: block? That way it should take up the whole width available but padding won't push it out further.